# Change "Find Symbol Results" format for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a way to change the formatting of the results list for the `Find Symbol Results` window in Visual Studio (Originally asked in regards to 2013 but I'm not using 2017)?

I found [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saraford/archive/2006/03/30/customize-your-find-in-files-results-experience.aspx) but it is for the `Find Results` window not the `Find Symbol Results`.

Ultimately I just want the symbol results window to show the relative path instead of the entire local path.

Comment: Did you ever manage to figure this one out?

Comment: Unfortunately not.